# Codeigniter Callback functions for file validations are not working

Tags: codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I've created validation rules for image uploading as follows.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('display_photo', 'Display Photo', 'callback_file_required|callback_file_size_max[1000]');
```

In controller I've included callback function as follows.

```
     public function file_required($display_photo) {

        if($_FILES[$display_photo]['size'] == 0) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('file_required', 'Upload a file.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }

      public function file_size_max($display_photo, $max_size) {

        if($_FILES[$display_photo]['size'] > $max_size) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('file_size_max', 'This file exceeds max size.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
```

Only first rule is executing but not second rule. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: one way - you can vlaidate when file is uploaded!

Comment: @Suleman Before uploading I wanted the validation so..

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the file size limit in the config not in the validation rule.
Can u please paste the function or method that performs the upload ?

Comment: Just validating the image not written code for uploading yet. Anyway If I'm passing argument that function should work right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('display_photo', 'Display Photo', 'callback_file_required_with_validation');

 public function file_required_with_validation($display_photo) {

    $max_size=1000;

    if($_FILES[$display_photo]['size'] == 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('file_required', 'Upload a file.');
        return false;
    }

    if($_FILES[$display_photo]['size'] > $max_size) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('file_size_max', 'This file exceeds max size.');
        return false;
    }     
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use two callbacks on a single field when validation forms in CI. In any case you don't need to check the size to see if a file was uploaded. Use error code '4'

Solutions:

- Check if the file was uploaded with `if($_FILES[$display_photo]['error'] !== 4) // Error code 4 means no file was uploaded. So if it's not 4 then you have a file.`
- If you want to do multiple checks you can put them both in one single callback

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need double underscore after 'callback' in your validation definition...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('display_photo', 'Display Photo', 'callback__file_required|callback__file_size_max[1000]');
```

Answer (score -1):

One way - You can validate with `JS` before uploading the file:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    if(file && file.size < 10485760) { // 10 MB (this size is in bytes)
        //Submit form        
    } else {
        //Prevent default and display error
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

[Original Question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload)

But if you want validate at server side, then server until does't know whenever we upload the file.

Comment: Server does't know until we upload the file!

Comment: @Sanganabasu: I think you are talking about, send request to server and before saving the file. But logically how does server knows until we do't send the req.