# Check if a file extension is not changed before uploading in php

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, extension-methods

I have to upload a pdf type of file only. There are different ways by which we can check the extension of the file like $_FILES['files']['type'] or pathinfo() function. But what if a person changes the extension of the file before uploading.
Example.
If a person changes a png file from image.png to image.pdf. Then how can I check that the uploaded file is not a pdf?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php MIME Type

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload

Comment: All valid PDF files start with the 4 bytes `%PDF`

Comment: Checking extension is easy. But checking that the file is an actual PDF. Much harder. Maybe you can get a PDF reader and verify that it can open and read the pdf.

Comment: @Bouffe still didn't find how to ensure that the file extension is not changed!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo mime_content_type('form.pdf');
```

check more info in http://php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php

EDIT:

I rename a .zip file to .pdf file

```
if(isset($_FILES['archivo']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']))
{

 $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
 $archivo_name = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

echo mime_content_type($archivo);

 move_uploaded_file($archivo, "upload/" . $archivo_name);

}
```

the script above print application/zip

Then you can do something like this:

```
if (mime_content_type($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) == 'application/pdf') {
//ok is a pdf
}
```

Comment: Any better method? As this shows text/plain for some of the pdfs!

Comment: as the manual say you can use  $_FILES['userfile']['type'] but this mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted. Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php