# How to check file size in PHP before uploading to temp folder?

Tags: php, file, validation, upload, web

How do I verify that a file isn't too big to upload in php before uploading it to the temp folder?

This line:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= 10485760)
```

will not work because the file gets uploaded to the temp directory first. I already have an Ajax solution that works perfectly. I am trying to code for when scripting is disabled.

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-341) I can prevent a user from having to wait for a file to upload before receiving an error message stating that it's too big by using this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
```

but that does not work. All it does it change the maximum file size to 30000.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading

Comment: How would PHP, running on the server, know whether the file is too big without it first being on the server?

Comment: Filegetsize()  use this function

Comment: @Mihai *"I already have an Ajax solution that works perfectly. I am trying to code for when scripting is disabled."*

Comment: The php.ini settings won't stop the file being uploaded, but they will deal with it immediately before it starts executing your php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11514290/ ***"Server Side Upload Canceling"***

Comment: What do u mean scripting disabled?

Comment: @MuhammedM. he means if user disables JS. He want to use a serverside method not client-side.

Comment: My method is server side, when we say php it is server side, nothing client side

Comment: @MuhammedM. read the question again, he's basically after a client-side solution that's **not** JavaScript ... which I don't think exists yet.

Comment: **A:** Basically you can't avoid it. In a way you can, but by the time the server checks to see if it's more than what is allowed, the person sending the file already spent the time uploading it and that may not wash very well if the limit is say... 40 mb and they uploaded a 50mb file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- according to the PHP manual I can avoid it, but I tried their solution and it won't work for me. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As users have stated in the comments, this cannot be done in PHP. The PHP manual is wrong, as it clearly states I can prevent a user from having to wait for the upload to complete before giving them an error because the files too big by using this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
```

In future, I won't use `php.net` as a reference. I'll just stick to using Stack Overflow.